# SuiteScript 1.0: Custom button to copy sublist of unsubmitted cash sale to invoice

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I'm trying to create a script that adds a custom button on an **unsubmitted** cash sale that, when pressed, copies the item sublist (varying line item count), creates a new invoice on another tab, and sets the values from the cash sale sublist to the invoice. I've figured out how to create the button that creates a new invoice, but I'm stuck trying to figure out how to copy over the values.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
function beforeLoad_addButton(type, form) {
   form.setScript('customscript_thsi_open_inv_6');
   form.addButton('custpage_splitpayment', 'Split Payment', 'onclick_CreateInvoice()');  
} 

function onclick_CreateInvoice(){
    var url = nlapiResolveURL('record', 'invoice', null, 'edit') + '?case_id=' + nlapiGetRecordId();
window.open(url, "New Invoice");}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Window.open()` returns a Window object which you can use to run SS1.0 functions in the new tab.

```
function onclick_CreateInvoice() {
  var url = nlapiResolveURL('record', 'invoice', null, 'edit') + '?case_id=' + nlapiGetRecordId();
  var invoiceWindow = window.open(url, "New Invoice");
  invoiceWindow.nlapiSetFieldValue('entity', nlapiGetFieldValue('entity'));
  invoiceWindow.nlapiSetFieldValue('trandate', nlapiGetFieldValue('trandate'));
}
```

Comment: Hi, michoel - thank you very much for your answer.  Will this script copy the "item" sublist over to the invoice?

Comment: No, the snippet just copies over the `entity` and `trandate` fields. It's just intended to illustrate the technique, you can adapt to copy other main line and/or sublists.